Google analytics link to BigQuery is policy Org sensitive?
I tried linking Google Analytics 360 to BigQuery project in GCP but I had error related to policy Organization. When I disbaled the Policy Org : "resource locations : europe" ( I allowed all regions), the link was up and functioning.
I would like to understand why, if someone can explain...
Thank you.
